# How to add custom Nginx Request header (to proxy to backend) at runtime?

Tags: nginx

So I have a need to add a custom header to current request, based on some attribute to the current connection. That means the header value cannot be pre-determined at config time.

That means I will have to do such thing in source code. Does anyone have any pointers on what's the easiest way to accomplish this? I think I will have to dig into the implementation of either [proxy_set_header](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_proxy_module.c#3406) or [more_set_input_headers](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module/blob/master/src/ngx_http_headers_more_headers_in.c#L459) from headers more module, and borrow the relevant implementation detail to the place I want to insert my custom header.

Both implementations seem very complicated and not even look alike. Which one is easier for me to adopt and use? Is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks!